# Ошибка при запуске конвертированного exe файла

Tags: python, веб-программирование, eel, auto-py-to-exe

Я написал программу на pyhton с использованием web интерфейса( я использовал библиотеку Eel). И решил конвертировать его в exe файл, но после запуска выскакивает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "eel\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "bottle.py", line 73, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Я много чего перепробовал менял версии Eel, указывал все зависимые файлы, даже ChatGPT просил помочь, но он ничем не помог

Comment: Пробовали конвертировать в "One Directory" и смотреть все ли зависимости были собраны?

Comment: Да, с самого начала так и делал